# Two domains, same data. PHP Application loses Session vars on only one of them, how?

Tags: php, apache, session

I have two domains pointing towards the same data on a web server. I do not host the web server myself, but the application is built by me. The application simply starts the session, prints the session array and then sets a variable in the session. When you first start it its empty, when you refresh it the printed array shows the value that had been set before the refresh. This works for domain1, but for domain2 the printed array stay's empty. How is that possible?

These are not sub-domains. They are full www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com domains.

The webserver is Apache (I dont know anything about Apache, but any answer I could pass along to my Host is welcome).
The application is PHP 5.

Some extra info: I have a reseller account I use with DirectAdmin. Domain1 (the one that works) has its own data, Domain2 (the one that doesn't work) has a VHost that points towards the data of Domain1. I cannot manage the VHost myself, but as this is a SaaS application where all domains should point towards the same software the Hosting company was nice enough to set it up like this. I don't know if this is relevant, but I though I'd share it.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are set with a domain. What is set on domain1.com is not available to domain2.com. PHP sessions are often stored into PHPSSID cookies, which could explain the thing.

Have a look a your cookies, you'll see they're linked to domains. Look for the domain1.com PHPSSID.

Comment: I do not want to share the session between different domains. I simply want my session vars on domain2 to be remembered in domain2. This is not the case. Its working for domain1, but domain2 seems to loose its session vars with every pagerefresh.

Comment: Well, even though you're using different domains, the machine using the session behind is the same. Maybe it gets confused by received the same PHPSSID, from a "different place". Maybe you could try using `session_regenerate_id(true)`.